# Is it possible to change ionic package name prior to ionic start?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I know it's possible to change the package name by modifying the config.xml file. As seen [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346127/cordova-ionic-framework-how-to-safely-change-package-name). 
But is it possible to specify the package name prior to the creation of the project, like we do on cordova?

Cordova example: `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

Now, on Ionic, is it possible to do something similar?

Comment: `ionic help` is your friend

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ionic start -a todo -i com.carlosrojasblog.todo todo blank
```

change [`todo`] for your project name and [`com.carlosrojasblog.todo`] for your  own package name.